# Designer error when inheriting forms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, inheritance

When I inherit a base form I get the following error when trying to open the designer:

> "The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the
>   classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the
>   following classes in the file: frmTest --- The base class
>   'TestInherit.BaseForm' could not be loaded. Ensure the assembly has
>   been referenced and that all projects have been built."

In the designer code I use "Inherits BaseForm" (= Windows form) instead of the default "Inherits `System.Windows.Forms.Form`".

What am I doing wrong here?

NB: If you want you can download a test project here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5391091/TestInherit.rar

NB: I want/need all (base) forms in the same assembly.

NB: The same technique works without any problem when using Telerik forms. See this example project, using Telerik: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5391091/TestInheritTelerik.rar

Comment: Do you have make a build before you open the design form?

Comment: Put the base form in an separate assembly, build it, and reference it to the assembly that must inherit `BaseForm`

Comment: Putting the BaseForm in an other assembly isn't a great option to be honest, as both forms use shared classes that are protected (only accessible from within the same assembly).

Comment: If you want to use the visual desginer you don't have a choice. `protected` members are visible at the class's that interet the base class. It sounds like you are talking about `internal` members. If that is the case, there is [a way around that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) as wall

Comment: Can you add code (as in: put your own code) into the Telerik forms's .dll ?!

Comment: @Jens: Yes, I can put my own code in the Telerik base form, and be located in the same assembly.

Comment: Forgive me, for not believe in you.(I really mean that) There is a paradox in that - becuase the base form need to *execute* a design time, it need to be compiled *before* the concrete form. If the two forms are in the same assembly, it means that the base form cannot be compiled before the contrete form. you see the problem?

Comment: @Jens: See my "prove": https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5391091/TestInheritTelerik.rar. I have put a messagebox in both base as derived form. They both show up, and I can open each form in designer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30063/discussion-between-jens-kloster-and-mike-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I posted in comments, the solution is to move the base form to a different assembly.

[image]
(pardon the other project is C#, i could not add a VB.NET proj)

Look at inhereted form now:

[image]

all I did was to add `Import` to frmTest.Designer.vb:
[image]

The reason for this, is becuase the VS visualizer actually creates an running instance of the base form, when you are designen `frmTest`!